# Javascript form validation not working with one field but works with the others

Tags: javascript, validation

I for some reason can not get the rep id field to validate with my script. I've spent hours on it and can't figure it out. All other fields validate just fine except the repid.

Here is the code I am using for the form

```
       <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="repsignup" id="repsignup">
      <h1>Janoo Rep Sign Up</h1>
      <p>Join our growing team and help rep Janoo out there in the world!</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <h4>
        Name (First and Last):
        <input name="name" type="text" required="required" id="name" form="repsignup" placeholder="John Doe" size="70" maxlength="70" />
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="repid">Rep ID:</label>
        <input name="repid" type="text" id="repid" form="repsignup" placeholder="DoeJ" size="32" maxlength="15" /> 
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required="required" id="email" form="repsignup" placeholder="Jdoe@gmail.com" size="89" maxlength="100" />
      </h4>
      <p><strong>* Your default password is &quot;password&quot; all lowercase! Please change it as soon as you log in.</strong></p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>*As of right now we only have reps in the United States</p>
      <h4>
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input name="address" type="text" required="required" id="address" form="repsignup" placeholder="12345 Street" size="86" />
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input name="city" type="text" required="required" id="city" form="repsignup" placeholder="Detroit" size="92" />
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="country">State:</label>
        <input name="State" type="text" required="required" id="address3" form="repsignup" placeholder="ex. MI" size="90" maxlength="2" />
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="address5">Zipcode:</label>
        <input name="zipcode" type="text" required="required" id="address5" form="repsignup" placeholder="48201" size="87" />
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
        <select name="gender" size="1" id="gender" form="repsignup">
<option value="Null">No Answer</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
        <input name="birthday" type="date" required="required" id="birthday" form="repsignup" />
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="about">About you:<br />
        </label>
        <textarea name="about" cols="100" rows="10" maxlength="250" id="about" form="repsignup"></textarea>
      </h4>
      <h4>
        <label for="shirtsize">Shirt Size:</label>
        <select name="shirtsize" id="shirtsize" form="repsignup">
          <option value="as">Adult Small</option>
          <option value="am">Adult Medium</option>
          <option value="al">Adult Large</option>
          <option value="axl">Adult XL</option>
          <option value="axxl">Adult XXL</option>
        </select>
      </h4>
      <h4>What team are you appling for? (Select all that apply)  </h4>
      <p>
        <input name="skate" type="checkbox" id="skate" form="repsignup" />
        <label for="skate">Skateboard </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="snow" type="checkbox" id="snow" form="repsignup" />
        <label for="snow">Snowboard </label>
</p>
      <p>
        <input name="longboard" type="checkbox" id="longboard" form="repsignup" />
        Longboard
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="video" type="checkbox" id="video" form="repsignup" />
        Video Production
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="music" type="checkbox" id="music" form="repsignup" />
        Music Production
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="model" type="checkbox" id="model" form="repsignup" />
        <label for="model">Modeling </label>
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <h4>Links to your contacts</h4>
      <p>
        <label for="instagram">Instagram:</label>
        <input name="instagram" type="text" id="instagram" form="repsignup" size="86" maxlength="80" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="facebook">Facebook:</label>
        <input name="facebook" type="text" id="facebook" form="repsignup" size="86" maxlength="80" />
</p>
      <p>
        <label for="twitter">Twitter:</label>
        <input name="twitter" type="text" id="twitter" form="repsignup" size="86" maxlength="80" />
</p>
      <p>
        <label for="youtube">YouTube:</label>
        <input name="youtube" type="text" id="youtube" form="repsignup" size="86" maxlength="80" />
</p>
      <p>
        <label for="website">Website:</label>
        <input name="website" type="text" id="website" form="repsignup" size="86" maxlength="80" />
</p>
      <p>
        <label for="otherlinks">Other:</label>
        <input name="otherlinks" type="text" id="otherlinks" form="repsignup" size="86" maxlength="80" />
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><strong>Here is some stuff you should read up on:</strong></p>
      <p>Reps are paid out when they hit $5 in commison.</p>
      <p>Rep codes do NOT work with coupons.</p>
      <p>Default commison is 10% of all your sales but may vary.</p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <p><strong>For any of your media content to be used you must agree to the <a href="media terms.php" target="new">the terms and conditions</a></strong></p>
      <p>
        <input name="media" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="media" form="repsignup" checked="checked" />
      I agree to <a href="media terms.php" target="new">the terms and conditions</a> for usage of my media and allow the promotion of me as a individual  </p>
      <p>
        <input name="inform" type="checkbox" id="inform" form="repsignup" checked="checked" />
        <label for="inform">Inform me of my sales</label> 
        as a rep
      </p>
      <p>
        <input name="DATE" type="hidden" id="DATE" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
        <input name="com" type="hidden" id="com" form="repsignup" value="10" />
        <input name="country" type="hidden" id="country" value="United States of America" />
        <input name="password" type="hidden" id="password" form="repsignup" value="861aab8d5bdd93565a7454e5e5754f8f" />
        <input name="1" type="hidden" id="1" value="1" />
        <input name="discount" type="hidden" id="discount" value="5" />
        <input name="2" type="hidden" id="2" value="2" />
        <input name="enddate" type="hidden" id="enddate" value="3000-01-01 00:00:00" />
        <input name="avail" type="hidden" id="avail" value="30000000" />
      </p>
      <p>
      <?php print imageorsubmit(@$imgsubmit,$GLOBALS['xxSubmt'],'submit')?></p>
      <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="repsignup" />
      </p>
    </form>
```

And here is the javascript I am using to validate it

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#repsignup").submit(function(event){
          //alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
          var name =        $("#name").val();
          var repid =       $("#repid").val();
          var address =     $("#address").val();
          var city =        $("#city").val();
          var state =       $("#address3").val();
          var zipcode =     $("#address5").val();
          var gender =      $("#gender").val();
          var birthday =    $("#birthday").val();
          var about =       $("#about").val();
          var skate =       $("#skate").val();
          var snow =        $("#snow").val();
          var longboard =   $("#longboard").val();
          var video =       $("#video").val();
          var music =       $("#music").val();
          /*Social fields*/
          var instagram =   $("#instagram").val();
          var facebook =    $("#facebook").val();
          var twitter =     $("#twitter").val();
          var youtube =     $("#youtube").val();
          var website =     $("#website").val();
          var otherlinks =  $("#otherlinks").val();

          //alert(name.split(" ").length);
          var a = isValidCharacter(name);
          //alert(a);

          /*Name validation*/
          if(name.split(" ").length==2 && a)
            ;
          else{
            alert('Please enter first and last name separated by a space. No special character is allowed');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          validRepid = isValidCharacter(repid);
          if(repid.indexOf('>') > -1 || repid.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Rep ID should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          validAddress = isValidCharacter(address);
          if(address.indexOf('>') > -1 || address.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Address should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          validCity = isValidCharacter(city);
          if(city.indexOf('>') > -1 || city.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('City should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          validState = isValidCharacter(state);
          if(state.indexOf('>') > -1 || state.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('State should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          validZipcode = isValidCharacter(zipcode);
          if(zipcode.indexOf('>') > -1 || zipcode.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Zipcode should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          validGender = isValidCharacter(gender);
          if(gender.indexOf('>') > -1 || gender.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Gender should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          if (birthday.indexOf('>') > -1 || birthday.indexOf('<') > -1)
          {
            alert('Birthday should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          validAbout = isValidCharacter(about);
          if(!validAbout){
            alert('About field should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          var flag = false;
          if($("#skate").prop("checked"))
            flag = true;
          if($("#snow").prop("checked"))
            flag = true;
          if($("#skate").prop("checked"))
            flag = true;
          if($("#longboard").prop("checked"))
            flag = true;
          if($("#video").prop("checked"))
            flag = true;
          if($("#music").prop("checked"))
            flag = true;
          if($("#model").prop("checked"))
            flag = true;

          if(flag==false){
            alert('Please select at least one team to apply for.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          if(instagram.indexOf('>') > -1 || instagram.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Instagram field should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          if(facebook.indexOf('>') > -1 || facebook.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Facebook field should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

          if(twitter.indexOf('>') > -1 || twitter.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Twitter field should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          if(youtube.indexOf('>') > -1 || youtube.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Youtube field should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          if(website.indexOf('>') > -1 || website.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Website field should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          if(otherlinks.indexOf('>') > -1 || otherlinks.indexOf('<') > -1){
            alert('Otherlinks field should not have any special character.');
            event.preventDefault();
          }

      });
  });

  function isValidCharacter(str){
    return !/[~`#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: that is not java, I am sure you meant javascript & jQuery?

Comment: anyway, you'd have to be more specific , what exactly is the problem? what happens that is not expected?

Comment: You never do anything with the variables `validRepid`, `validAddress`, `validCity`, etc. The only validation you're doing is checking for `>` and `<`.

Comment: please remove all form="repsignup" properties from your input fields. you have a form tag around the fields, thats all what you need

Comment: Thanks I got it. Yes I meant jQuery and Java, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can validate all fields without getting each single value and only using one function for it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var allFine = true;

  function valdiate(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value !== null && value.trim().length() > 0 && !value.match(/[\<\>]/));
    var allFine = false;
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
  }

  // selector for all required input and textarea tags in your html
  $('form').find('input:required, textarea:required').each(validate); 

  $('form').on('submit', function(){
    if(!allFine) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagination();
      alert('there is a failure, have a look on the red bordered fields');
    }
    // otherwise the form is submitted normal
  });
})
```

if you need to check all input fields for validation, remove the :required flag in the selector and remove null and length check from the if

remember, if you use html5 you also can use pattern attribute to input element with regex:

```
<input name="myInput" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 .,-]" required>
```

or some other regex you want